# Crash when starting depth camera

Tags: gazebo-1.3

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi There,

I'm experimenting with the 1.3 release of Gazebo that has just been included with Ros Groovy.  I am attempting to run a simulation of the new kobuki based turtlebot.  What I am finding is that with a little experimentation I have gotten the model to launch, but the simulator appears to crash when generating the depth camera for the Kinect sensor.

```
Warning [parser.cc:499] XML Attribute[range] in element[attenuation] not defined in SDF, ignoring.
Warning [parser.cc:499] XML Attribute[xyz] in element[direction] not defined in SDF, ignoring.
[New Thread 0x7fffdae56700 (LWP 10220)]
[New Thread 0x7fffda655700 (LWP 10221)]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[New Thread 0x7fffd9e54700 (LWP 10223)]
[New Thread 0x7fffd9653700 (LWP 10224)]
[New Thread 0x7fffd8e52700 (LWP 10225)]
[New Thread 0x7fffc3fff700 (LWP 10232)]
[New Thread 0x7fffc37fe700 (LWP 10233)]
[New Thread 0x7fffc2ffd700 (LWP 10234)]
[ INFO] [1359430250.570906834]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 129.96.183.176
Error [Rendering.cc:37] Failed to load the Rendering engine subsystem
unable to find OpenGL rendering system. OGRE is probably installed incorrectly. Double check the OGRE cmake output, and make sure OpenGL is enabled.
[New Thread 0x7fffc16fc700 (LWP 10266)]
[New Thread 0x7fffc0efb700 (LWP 10267)]
[New Thread 0x7fffabfff700 (LWP 10274)]
Warning [parser.cc:377] SDF has no  element in file[data-string]
Dbg [base_footprint] has no parent joint
Warning [parser.cc:314] parse from urdf.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff55f9838 in std::basic_string, std::allocator >::basic_string(std::string const&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff55f9838 in std::basic_string, std::allocator >::basic_string(std::string const&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff2048da4 in gazebo::rendering::Scene::CreateDepthCamera(std::string const&, bool) () from /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/lib/libgazebo_rendering.so.1
#2  0x00007ffff6b77eac in gazebo::sensors::DepthCameraSensor::Init() () from /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/lib/libgazebo_sensors.so.1
#3  0x00007ffff6b8d468 in gazebo::sensors::SensorManager::Update(bool) () from /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/lib/libgazebo_sensors.so.1
#4  0x000000000042811f in gazebo::Server::Run() ()
#5  0x00000000004247af in main ()
(gdb)
```

Commenting out the Kinect sensor in the robot description allows the simulation to launch.

```
[New Thread 0x7fffdae56700 (LWP 11532)]
[New Thread 0x7fffda655700 (LWP 11533)]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[New Thread 0x7fffd9e54700 (LWP 11535)]
[New Thread 0x7fffd9653700 (LWP 11536)]
[New Thread 0x7fffd8e52700 (LWP 11537)]
[New Thread 0x7fffc3fff700 (LWP 11544)]
[New Thread 0x7fffc37fe700 (LWP 11545)]
[New Thread 0x7fffc2ffd700 (LWP 11546)]
[ INFO] [1359430908.947420043]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 129.96.183.176
Error [Rendering.cc:37] Failed to load the Rendering engine subsystem
unable to find OpenGL rendering system. OGRE is probably installed incorrectly. Double check the OGRE cmake output, and make sure OpenGL is enabled.
[New Thread 0x7fffc16fc700 (LWP 11581)]
[New Thread 0x7fffc0efb700 (LWP 11584)]
[New Thread 0x7fffabfff700 (LWP 11588)]
Warning [parser.cc:377] SDF has no  element in file[data-string]
Dbg [base_footprint] has no parent joint
Warning [parser.cc:314] parse from urdf.
spawn status:  SpawnModel: successfully spawned model
Error [Plugin.hh:126] Failed to load plugin libgazebo_ros_kobuki.so: libgazebo_ros_kobuki.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[New Thread 0x7fffab7fe700 (LWP 11595)]
[ INFO] [1359430909.981870169, 0.023000000]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
[ INFO] [1359430910.048695962, 0.073000000]: Starting to spin physics dynamic reconfigure node...
```

There appear to be errors in the [robot description](https://github.com/yujinrobot/kobuki/issues/156), but appears to be under development.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1104/crash-when-starting-depth-camera/) by [JonW](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7/jonw/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-01-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This error:

```
Error [Rendering.cc:37] Failed to load the Rendering engine subsystem unable to find OpenGL  rendering system. OGRE is probably installed incorrectly. Double check the OGRE cmake output, and make sure OpenGL is enabled.
```

indicates that Gazebo was unable to find OpenGL, which could mean that your machine doesn't have an opengl driver installed. This is required for the kinect style sensor.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0